# Desktop fans becomes too loud after 30mins

Tags: hardware-failure, gpu, fan

I am having a problem with loudness of my desktop

```
Configuration
AMD Athlon X4 750k (3.4ghz, FM2)
AMD Radeon R7 250 1gb DDR5
2x 4gb HyperX Kingston Ram
1x HDD Seagate 500gb 7200RPM
1x SSD Transcend 64gb (low-class)
500W power supply
```

There are two oddities in my opinion and I would like hear thoughts on this.

1.PSU can't carry this configuration and therefore it is heating and fan becomes too loud 
2. I have this very unusual situation (I do not know, maybe it is normal) that GPU fan is working at 750k RPM, it just seems too much...

[image: 750k RPM GPU Fan]

Comment: 1) And you're using which operating system and using the system for what? 2) Are you aware that SpeedFan shows wrong values depending on the hardware?

Comment: It seems your system is ramping up after 30 minutes in order to cool itself down.  If it was right away I'd say your fan speed was set to high however you comment that it takes 30 minutes to do so.  Maybe you have a lof of dust in your machine that doesn't allow your system to cool down.  My brothers system would simply overheat and quit after a while.  He asked me to fix it.  I opened it up, used canned air to remove all the dust; after this his computer ran fine.  Also make sure your fan has enough ventilation in order to allow itself to cool down.  Don't block any venting that allows coolin

Comment: The 750k RPM GPU fan is definitely showing wrong values. The outer part of a 80mm fan at 750k RPM would be traveling at 2.6 times the speed of sound (2005 miles per hour | 3226 kilometers per hour (896 meters per second). Try another tool to see if you can get a proper reading.

Comment: 1) Windows 10 2) I get these same stats in other software for eg HWmonitor.

I dusted the computer a few days ago and it wasn't that dirty. I'm really not sure. Will probably open it now to see which fan causes this loudness.

Comment: Is it a 4 pin fan where you can control the fan speed with your BIOS?

Comment: @Dale Yes, it is 4pin and I can control it.

Comment: The GPU seems REALLY high.  750k RPM is NUTS!

Comment: A few things.  1) I would confirm that it is in fact the GPU fan that is making all the noise.  Open up the box while it's running and check that first (if you haven't done so already).  2) Then try to turn down the fan speed using the setting right there on the controller to 30% or whatever you prefer.  If that in fact helps great.  3) Does Radeon have it's own software to control the fan speeds on your system.  I know on my ASUS GFX 970 I do.  Maybe that software is cranking up the speed.  If so you may want to try controlling the fan speed with that software if this doesn't work.

Comment: Firstly the GPU reading is obviously wrong. Secondly, how loud is too loud, Finally. You can't do anything useful until you find out where the noise is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the fan speed is incorrect. One thing we can't tell on this forum is if the fan being "too loud" is the fan malfunctioning (ie rubbing on something) or performing normal.  If it is indeed running normal (free of dust and obstruction) then I would check the temperatures your computer is reaching before just lowering the fan speed since the fan is running fast for a reason. You don't simply want to turn it down if temperatures are high.

If your temperatures are spiking high then you will need to investigate why before turning the speeds down.  If the temperatures seem fine and if the fan is operating normally then using software specific to your motherboard, or third party software, should allow you to lower the speed.

If you don't like the performance / heat trade-off from lowering the speed then you may want to look at aftermarket CPU coolers as there are some pretty good ones out there that don't make a lot of noise.